# Why does SignalR use IList in its contracts and everywhere in its internals instead of IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm sending messages to individual users depending on their roles, to accomplish that I have the following piece of code:

```
public static void Add(Guid userId, IEnumerable<SnapshotItem> snapshot)
{
    var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<FeedbackHub>();

    var items = ApplicationDbContext.Instance.InsertSnapshot(userId, Guid.NewGuid(), snapshot);

    foreach (var sendOperation in ConnectedUsers.Instance.EnumerateSendOperations(items))
    {
        hub.Clients.Users(sendOperation.Groups.SelectMany(x => x.Users).Select(x => x.Id).ToList()).OnDataFeedback(sendOperation.Items);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why do I have to invoke `.ToList()` each time I need to send something, my backing store is `HashSet<String>` and I want SignalR to work with that type of store instead of converting it to `List` each time since it would obviously consume processing power and memory.

Since in the backstage SignalR is doing simple iteration over the argument users or connectionIds, wouldn't it be more wise to use `IEnumerable` instead of `IList`, I've looked into the SignalR sources, shouldn't be to hard to achieve? Is there a particular reason for using the `IList`?

---

**Edit**

Created an issue on SignalR github page, will have to wait for one of the actual devs in order to clear things out...

Comment: Well, you'd have to ask the developer to get the right answer, right?

Comment: I have to ask Stackoverflow first, right? ;)

Comment: But the way your question is asked, noone can really answer it unless the actual developer shows up to answer it

Comment: @Patrick not necessarily, someone with enough understanding of the source could explain it.

Comment: If this data is being sent asynchronously, it's probably safest to simply get the data eagerly instead of holding a reference to whatever is responsible for providing the data (that's at least one way to look at it). But, on the other hand, you could then argue that it would be more efficient if the entire message was built at once (it has to be built anyway, at some point) by immediately iterating through the `IEnumerable` and then used in the async part.

Comment: @Stijn: Well then it would still only be guessing what the developer intended in the first place. Who is to say what a "correct" answer to this question is?

Comment: @Groo: in any case the system will maintain reference until Task is completed, as for waiting for a developer of SignalR I would say the following: if you have nothing to say, say nothing :)

Comment: @Lu4: reference to what? Having a list reference is not the same as having a `IEnumerable` reference. In the latter case, you can pass an `IQueryable`, for example, and still have lazy evaluation, and an arbitrary LINQ provider can easily fail at runtime. Example: open a connection, use your favorite ORM LINQ provider, pass the `IQueryable` to SignalR, close the connection. By the time your task starts running, the provider cannot access the data anymore. There is no definite answer to your question, it's simply a matter of developer's preference.

Comment: @Groo, yeah I get your point, but the SignalR implementation is creating tasks for each send operation, so the enumeration happens once after that the list of connections or users can be maintained as a part of the closure created for appropriate task...

Comment: @Groo I have found only one place where actual Add/Remove operations are used, its the `Subscription.EventKeys` property it is later is being used as a list, don't know what it is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no good reason for this as far as I can see digging through the older source code. The irony of it is that the `IList<string>` gets handed into the `MultipleSignalProxy` class where [it is promptly mapped to a different format using another LINQ expression](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/MultipleSignalProxy.cs#L24) and then that is `.ToList()`'d. So, based on that exact usage in the implementation, they really don't need anything more than `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Not the largest problem however, I see the `public abstract class Subscription : ISubscription, IDisposable` contains `public IList<string> EventKeys { get; private set; }` property which is later being manipulated via `private bool AddEventCore(string key)` and `public virtual void RemoveEvent(string key)`, specifically `EventKeys.Contains(key)`, `EventKeys.Add(key);` and `EventKeys.Remove(key);` calls are issued, what are those?

Comment: I see there are so much ToList operations inside SignalR, without knowing why is that happening looks scary, comparing to NodeJS Socket.io implementation SignalR looks like an overkill...

Answer (score 1):

My best answer would be that SignalR internally uses the enhanced function of IList like getting the count, or iterating over the collection and the additional use of index based access you would use for IList, but not ICollection.  The only reason to use the more robust class is because somewhere they are using it, or feel the need for that additional functionality.  Otherwise I would assume best practices of using the lighter class of ICollection, or IEnumerable, basically the base class of that Enumerable->Collection->List heirarchy.

G